# Is it possible to iterate through HTML-tree in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Example HTML ('x.html' in python snippet):

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <table><tr><td>c</td></tr></table>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get a list with three columns from a single row in table:

```py
[
  '<td>a</td>',
  '<td>b</td>',
  '<table><tr><td>c</td></tr></table>'
]
```

I tried to simply iterate over `BeautifulSoup` object but it returns entire HTML and empty (well, `'\n'`) string.

```py
In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(open('x.html').read(), 'html.parser')
In [10]: for a in soup: 
    ...:     print(type(a)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

I also tried to use `find_all()` method, but it finds the nested `<td>c</td>` which I don't want to see in results:

```py
In [24]: len(soup.find_all('td'))                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[24]: 4  # <-- I need 3 things, not 4
```

I thought that find/find_all parameter `recursive` is about nested elements, but I don't understand if it even works:

```py
Signature: soup.find_all(name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
In [26]: len(soup.find_all('td', recursive=False))                                                                                                                                                          
Out[26]: 0
```

Maybe writing `xml.sax` parser will be easier?

Comment: FYI, I don't believe having a `<table>` as a child of a `<tr>` is valid html.

Comment: `find` the outer `<tr>`, and then examine the `.contents` - you should see the tags children, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Danielle suggested in the comment, you can get the `.contents` of the outer `tr`. But since you are reading from this file you will get a number of `"\n"` and other unwanted elements with this. You can check if `isinstance(x,Tag)` to get only the tag contents.

In some situations with incorrect html , there might not be an simple solution like this. In those cases you can also pass a custom function to `find_all`. For Eg. The data that you are looking for can also be obtained with this logic - Find all `td` and `table` tags in the first table of the file. Of course, the logic can differ from this, but you get the idea.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Tag
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('x.html').read(), 'html.parser')
#solution 1
print([x for x in soup.find('tr').contents if isinstance(x,Tag)])
#solution 2 with a custom function
first_table=soup.find('table')
def is_td_or_table(item):
    if isinstance(item,Tag):
        if item.name in ['td','table'] and item.find_parent("table") is first_table:
            return True
print(first_table.find_all(is_td_or_table))
```